# 2 x 2 = 4 or 2 + 2 = 4 as an evident fact?

Tags: перевод, идиомы

In Tolstoy's [*Исповедь*](https://tolstoy.ru/online/online-publicism/ispoved/index.xhtml) one reads :

> Истина эта была всегда истина, как 2 × 2 = 4, но я не признавал ее, потому что, признав 2 × 2 = 4, я бы должен был признать то, что я нехорош.

2 x 2 = 4 is translated in French as : 2 + 2 = 4. Indeed, whenever we want to give an example of a fact that's evident, we use 2 + 2 = 4 rather than 2 x 2 = 4 (I believe it's the same in English). Does Russian in fact favor 2 x 2 = 4 in this usage instead of 2 + 2 = 4?

Comment: While I suspect you're right about the usual evident fact in English *today* being 2+2=4, long ago 2 x 2 = 4 was used at least once: there is a famous quote attributed to Lord Kelvin about the calculation of the Gaussian integral's value (the integral of exp(-x^2) over the real line being sqrt(pi)): "A mathematician is one to whom *that* is as obvious as that twice two makes four is to you."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Russian for "plain as a day" is *дважды два четыре*, literally "twice two four", or even just *дважды два*. It's unequivocally about multiplication.

> - Он же еще не умер. — Помрет, как дважды два. С третьего инфаркта еще никто не жил. [И. Грекова. На испытаниях (1967)]
> - Ясно и верно, как дважды два — четыре, что участь нашего друга держится на одной цепочке с тайною молдаванки. [И. И. Лажечников. Ледяной дом (1835)]
> - Я ей доказал как дважды два, что вы жили на взаимных выгодах: она капиталисткой, а ты при ней сентиментальным шутом. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Бесы (1871-1872)]

My guess is that it just goes more easily with the flow of speech than *два плюс два* or *два да два*, but I don't have anything to back that up with.